# Regex matching different numbers in meter presentation

Tags: regex, regex-group

I'm trying to match different variations of distance presentation which works pretty well for bigger values but fails on single digits

`^(?:(?<distanceMeter>\d+[,|.]?\d+?) ?\/? ?(?<distanceFemaleMeter>\d+?[,|.]?\d+?)?) ?-m ?(?<text>[\w\s]+)`
matches

- 2000/ 1,500-m row and
- 2000-m row

But it fails to match

- 10/ 5-m row
- 9-m row

I thought d+ always matches 1 or more digits, but its not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the pattern that you tried you use `\d+?` which matches at least 1 digits, and making it non greedy matches the least amount, but there still has to be at least a single digit.

**Note** that using `(?:\d+)?` is the same as `\d*`, and using `[\w\s]+` at the end can also match only whitespace chars (that can also match only newlines) You can use a space instead, as in the rest of the pattern you also match spaces.

---

Your examples should all match the digits at the start, and are followed by an optional `/` and digits part and then the `-m` part should be present followed by "text"

For that format, you can make the whole part with `/` and the digits optional.

```
^(?<distanceMeter>\d+(?:[,.]\d+)?)(?: ?\/ ?(?<distanceFemaleMeter>\d+(?:[,.]\d+)?))? ?-m ?(?<text>\w+(?: \w+)*)
```

- `^` Start of string
- `(?<distanceMeter>\d+(?:[,.]\d+)?)` Group *distanceMeter*, match 1+ digits with an optional decimal part
- `(?:` Non capture group

  - `?\/ ?` Match `/` between optional spaces
  - `(?<distanceFemaleMeter>\d+(?:[,.]\d+)?)` Group *distanceFemaleMeter*, match 1+ digits with an optional decimal part
- `)?` Close the non capture group and make it optional
- `?-m ?` Match `-m` between optional spaces
- `(?<text>\w+(?: \w+)*)` Group *text*, match 1+ word chars and optionally repeat a space and 1+ word chars

See a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/ksbUir/1).

Comment: Thanks a lot for that elaborate answer, this helped me!

Answer (score 0):

After posting I actually figured out that creating a new group can handle this, so instead of \d+? using (?:\d+)? works

```
^(?:(?<distanceMeter>\d+[,|.]?(?:\d+)?) ?\/? ?(?<distanceFemaleMeter>\d+?[,|.]?(?:\d+)?)?) ?-m ?(?<text>[\w\s]+)
```

Comment: If it worked, you can mark your own answer as accepted.